# Bluetooth Mode 1 Level 4 Security Concern

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

If I use LESC security (i.e. Level 4) but use Just Works pairing method instead of Pass Key pairing, will I still be using LESC security? i.e. my concern is that if I use Just Works pairing method with LESC, the Just Works pairing process will reduce the level of security to something less than 4.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the Bluetooth support, the Level is reduced to Level 2.